# My URL gets redirected but responseCode=200.Redirected URL have an ID which is not same every time when we hit the same URL.how to get redirected URL

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

I could not paste the URL for some security concern. The code is pretty simple and goes like this.URL gets redirected but response code is 200.how to get the redirected URL.

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Url {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int responseCode;
        try {
            String GET_URL=xxxxxxxx`;
            URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirected URL is handled automatically by [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). If you want to get the redirected URL, you should set the follow redirects to false and handle the redirect manually.

> setInstanceFollowRedirects
>
> public void setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean followRedirects)
>
> Sets whether HTTP redirects (requests with response code 3xx) should
>   be automatically followed by this HttpURLConnection instance.
>
> The default value comes from followRedirects, which defaults to true.